# Slow Composite Layers in chrome for 2D context drawing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-canvas

Im messing around a bit with HTML5 canvas and the 2D context and I get a weird behavior from Chrome's Composite Layers processing causing slow performance, around 30fps for a single rectangle with Composite Layers requiring 30ms per frame according to the performance tool in Chrome.

What makes me more confused is that it seems tightly connected to the size of the canvas. If I decrease the size from 1000x1000 to 500x500 the Composite Layers step goes down to 0.17ms which seems like a more reasonable duration.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-noyce-0080g?file=/index.html

Chrome version: 85.0.4183.83

[[image: Performance for 1000x10001]

[image: Performance for 500x500]

Comment: That makes sense. Composite layers are hardware accelerated. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60387428/why-hardware-accelerated-css-animation-cost-too-much-composite-layer-times-in

Comment: Right, it makes sense that it's higher but the huge increase is the part I'm confused about and wondering why it happens and what one can do about it.

Comment: Yeah it's strange. This is not an issue on Firefox

Comment: Yeah seems to work better in safari as well.

Comment: If the 31.22ms is from the example running at codesandbox.io it does not represent an accurate picture of what is going on, to the point of being meaningless and can be ignored. If the 31.22ms is from a standalone page with a total of 23 lines of HTML and JS then the problem is a configuration issue. Check chrome chrome://gpu/ for hardware problems  Also go to chrome://flags/ and click "Reset all" (Right of search at top of page) then restart and check using default configuration.

Comment: I got it from running the 'Open in a new window' mode in codesandbox. It does add some extra script tags but I got some similar results when running locally with only the necessary code. I'll check those out. Thanks!

Comment: Enabling the 'Override software rendering list' reduced the Composite Layers processing to 0.2ms so I'd say that answers my questions. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks all!